# Asterisk own function - execution time

Tags: asterisk, voip

I wrote a custom function for Asterisk. It there any max execution time for running it from dialplan?

Best Regards, 
Matt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no limit from asterisk side.

But if your channel not answered yet, it will be hanguped from other side when timeout reached.

Comment: unless you make use of [Dial() option "g"](https://wiki.asterisk.org/wiki/display/AST/Application_Dial), which will continue executing dialplan after the Dial command after the channel hangs up, or [DeadAGI](https://wiki.asterisk.org/wiki/display/AST/Asterisk+11+Application_DeadAGI)

Comment: No, that is not true. Behavour is different in different asterisk versions, but in most your app will be terminated if SOURCE channel timeout. g-option is for DESTINATION channel.

Comment: At current moment DeadAGI and AGI works exactly same, see source code.